# How do I override a value from a magento 2 lib LESS mixin?

Tags: magento2, theme, navigation, less, custom-theme

I have created my own theme using Blank Theme as it's base. In my theme, I have a file in `web/css/source/_navigation.less` As I understand, this file calls a mixin. `.lib-main-navigation();`which pulls everything that is included inside of it's definition at `lib/web/css/source/lib/_navigation.less` .

Inside this mixin, there is a value that is preventing my megamenu from functioning correctly.

```
.submenu {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 100% !important;
}
```

How do I edit the value for that class in a way that does not touch the magento lib files? As I dont want to override the core magento files.

Answer (score 0):

After a little tinkering, I discovered that I can simply create a copy of the lib folder and place it on the path `/vendor/theme/web/css/source/lib/_navigation.less` and it overwrote the native magento one.